# What are the different ways to use までもない?

Tags: grammar

I know the basics behind its grammatical function, but there isn't much out there giving the details and subtleties on its usage. Anyone know?

Comment: Also as までのこともない, but not very often.

Answer (score 1):

A few off my head.

これくらいの怪我なら病院に行くまでもない

My wound is not serious enough to go to hospital.

今日暑いことは言うまでもない

Needless to say its hot today.

As seen it usually means it doesn't need to do what ever the word right before it.

...I hope I'm making sense.